# WPF Image Style Trigger - small issue

Tags: wpf, triggers

i'm having a small issue with an style trigger on an image.  The trigger does change the source of the image, but when it does i lose the streght="fill" property.  I've also tried setting it in the trigger, but it seem to ignore it.  What am i missing here?

```
<Image x:Name="xBackground" 
        Height="99.5" 
        Width="271" 
        Stretch="Fill">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Green.png"  />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasAlarm}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Red.png" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Try reproducing this in a new solution to see if you still get this behavior.

Comment: Same, works fine. Check binding and DataContext.